# Is a meromorphic function satisfying $f(2z)=\frac{f(z)}{1+f(z)^2}$ constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $$f(2z)=\frac{f(z)}{1+f(z)^2}.$$

Extend it to a meromorphic function on the entire complex plane using this recursion. Must $f(z)$ be constant? I think so, but I can't prove it.

Substituting $g(z)=1/f(z)$ and rearranging yields

$$g(2z)=g(z)+\frac{1}{g(z)},$$

which seems useful, but I'm not sure how to proceed after that.

Comment: Hint: Use Schwarz's Lemma

Comment: @mwomath Doesn't that just lead to a longer version of the answers below? You see it has to be at most cubic then do the same computation as Hagen von Eitzen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $f(z)=z^kg(z)$ with $k>0$, $g$ holomorhic, $g(0)\ne0$.
Then $$2^kg(2z)=\frac{g(z)}{1+z^{2k}g(z)^2}$$
which gives a contradiction if we let $z=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f(0)=0$, write $f(z)=a_nz^n+O(z^{n+1})$ for some $n>0$.

Then
$$
\frac{f(z)}{1+f(z)^2}=(a_nz^n+O(z^{n+1}))(1-a_n^2z^{2n}+O(z^{4n}))=a_nz^n+O(z^{n+1})
$$
and
$$
f(2z)=2^na_nz^n+O(z^{n+1})
$$
which after equating coefficients implies that $a_n=0$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, $f$ must be identically zero.